# Automating creation of ServiceDefinition from Python script tool of ArcPy without broken project data source?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, python-script-tool

**Summary:** 
I can create a ServiceDefinition through ArcCatalog or ArcMap, but when I try to generate the ServiceDefinition through python, it does not copy the /data folder with it, thus the script fails when published to the server.

**Details:**

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2.3552

My toolbox script has one string input parameter and one string output parameter

I have a standard toolbox with custom Python script tools that I need to put on an ArcGIS server. The requirements from the system administrator is that I give him a .sd (ServiceDefinition) file.

I can successfully create the .sd file through ArcCatalog by running my python tool and then sharing it as a service. The problem with this is that it is a very long process, and every step (run the tool, right click result share as service, analyze the tool, stage the tool) takes a very long time.

What I am trying do is create a python script that will fully automate the process of creating a ServiceDefinition file.

When I AnalyzeForSD, I keep getting an error in the analyzeMessages saying:

> ERROR 001238: Script myTool contains broken project data source: data

I can't figure out how to resolve this error.

I figured I could just ignore the error and try to create the ServiceDefinition anyway. So then the .sd file is created, but it doesn't copy /data folder.

I have tried copy_data_to_server=True and =False, but neither one actually copies the data.

Any ideas?

Here's my directory structure

- Toolbox.tbx
- generateServiceDefinition.py
- ToolData

  - myTool.py
  - data

    - MapData.mxd
    - TextData.txt

Here is the script for creating the ServiceDefinition:

```
import arcpy
import sys
import os
scriptPath = sys.path[0]
toolboxPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'Toolbox.tbx')
sdDraftPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'Toolbox.sddraft')
sdPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'Toolbox.sd')

#import the toolbox
arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolboxPath, 'customModule')
#execute the tool
result = arcpy.myTool_customModule('hello')

try:
    os.remove(sdDraftPath)
except:
    pass
try:
    os.remove(sdPath)
except:
    pass

arcpy.CreateGPSDDraft(result, sdDraftPath, 'Toolbox', 
                        server_type="ARCGIS_SERVER",
                        copy_data_to_server=False, 
                        folder_name=None, 
                        summary='Summary', tags='Some Tags')


analyzeMessages = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(sdDraftPath)

if analyzeMessages['errors'] != {}:
    # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
    print analyzeMessages['errors']
    raise Exception('There were errors while generating the service definition')

arcpy.StageService_server(sdDraftPath, sdPath)
```

Here is myTool.py. Obviously this isn't my actual script, but it is an example that reproduces the problem.

```
import arcpy
import os 
import sys

input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#print input to the console
arcpy.AddMessage('You passed in ' + input)
scriptPath = sys.path[0]
#make a variable pointing to my data so that ESRi's code will realize 
#that this data needs to be packaged with the script
dataPath = os.path.join(scriptPath, 'data')
arcpy.AddMessage(dataPath)
mxdPath = os.path.join(dataPath, 'MapData.mxd')
#read a file from the data folder
dataFilePath = os.path.join(dataPath, 'TextData.txt')

with open(dataFilePath, 'r') as fin:
    arcpy.AddMessage(fin.read())

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd))
#write something to the output parameter
arcpy.SetParameterAsText(1, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd))
```

Comment: For the service definition script, what value are you getting for sys.path[0]?

Comment: For generateServiceDefinition.py, **sys.path[0] == "C:\export"**, for myTool.py, **sys.path[0] == "C:\export\ToolData"**

. So both sys.path[0] values are what I am expecting them to be.

Comment: You do not have the data source registered and you are not allowing the data to be copied `copy_data_to_server=False`

Comment: But the problem is, I do not want to copy the database data to the server, but I DO want to copy the other stuff in the folder to the server. And I don't have direct access to the server, so registering the data in the database with the server also doesn't help me create the SD either...

Comment: Have you confirmed that the Server admin is allowing this type of behavior?  The admin could have disabled the ability for you to copy data to the server.

Comment: The server admin isn't even involved at this point. I create the .sd file, open it like an archive using 7zip, and then look inside to see what it copied. Inside the .sd file, the /data folder (which contains mxds, images, etc...) is missing. When I run this whole process manually using ArcCatalog, the /data folder is included.

Comment: Manually checking the mxd, do you have any broken layer sources?

Comment: I hope that it does not seem harsh to close this as non-reproducible but it was asked a year ago, and in that time no has said that they can reproduce it nor provided any other answer.  Consequently, if you have not done so already I think this is one that you should be working through with Esri's Technical Support.